# Execute an Authorization Code Grant Flow Using Java Spring Rest Api

Tags: java, spring, jwt, authorization

I'm trying to call a 3rd party endpoint that requires authorization using Java spring rest Api, so I need to execute an Authorization Code Grant Flow.

I understand the flow where I need to **first** get the code **then** exchange the code for a JWT and **finally** use the JWT to be able to do the secure call.

What's not making sense to me is how am I suppose to set up a redirect URI when I'm using solely working with a backend rest api with no UI. Usually the user is redirected to a login page where they either login with a username/password or 3rd party accounts (google/facebook...)

After alot of googling, all the searches ended with guides to secure my own endpoints rather than access a secure endpoint from my spring boot service

Edit: It's worth mentioning that I'm using solely a backend with no front end (or MVC) whatsoever, after @Partha's comment I did the following:

**First**, I added a new login endpoint, when accessed via browser(this won't work with swagger/postman) it should redirect the user to the Authorization Server:

```
@GetMapping
public void login(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
    httpServletResponse.setHeader("Location", getAuthServerEndpoint());
    httpServletResponse.setStatus(302);
}
```

Where I built the endpoint to have all the data needed (client_id,redirect_uri...) so it looks something like

> https://idpserver.bla/oauth/authorize?client_id=xyz&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/token&response_type=code&scope=xyz

Now it sends me to the Login page of the auth Server, after I login, I expect it to redirect me to localhost/token (which is a get request that would retrieve the code and do a post request to get a jwt and save it) but instead, I'm receiving a invalid redirect uri and I'm really not sure if this is an issue from my implementation or the server's

**EDIT2:** I did a dumb mistake by NOT adding http://localhost:8080/token as a redirect url in the Auth Server since I assumed I didn't need to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure how are you trying.. idea here is .. your api server should have a get endpoint /login. In your controller of /login , you should redirect to IDP say http://idpserver.bla?client_id=xxx&grant_type=code&nonce=yyy&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/token ( note, its redirect, not make an api request ). So, with this, when you hit http://localhost:8080/login in ur browser, you should see it being redirected to IDP. now you enter ur credentials, IDP validates that and redirect back to http://localhost:8080/token?code=XYZABC or something similar. Your controller code of /token API should read the code from url param. and make a call (this is api call, not redirect) to IDP to exchange the code for a token ( idToken / accessToken) based on your scope. And using the token you should be able to access protected resources. Hope that helps

Comment: When I try to redirect, (public void method(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
    httpServletResponse.setHeader("Location", idpUrl);
    httpServletResponse.setStatus(302);
}) I get  An error has occurred The redirect uri included is not valid. and I'm not sure if it's an issue from my behalf or theirs. On a side note, is there anything that I need to escape in the url? (characters wise)

Comment: The IDP is asking for a username and password, after inserted correctly, displays an error saying the redirect uri is invalid... my uri: https://idpserver.bla/oauth/authorize?client_id=xyz&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/token&response_type=code&scope=xyz

Comment: Yes, which means when you registerd the client in IDP, you would have given one or many redirect url(s). Now, while using , you should only use one of those redirect url else it will say invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Depending if you are using **MVC** or **Webflux** a different approach will be required:

- **MVC**: include a "security filter" to do that. You will be able to see an example in the following links:

[MVC Securiry Manager](https://github.com/doctore/Spring5Microservices/blob/master/order-service/src/main/java/com/order/configuration/security/SecurityManager.java)

[MVC Security Filter](https://github.com/doctore/Spring5Microservices/blob/master/order-service/src/main/java/com/order/configuration/security/filter/SecurityFilter.java)

[MVC Security Configuration](https://github.com/doctore/Spring5Microservices/blob/master/order-service/src/main/java/com/order/configuration/security/WebSecurityConfiguration.java)

- **Webflux**: configure your own security manager. You will be able to see an example in the following links:

[Webflux Securiry Manager](https://github.com/doctore/Spring5Microservices/blob/master/pizza-service/src/main/java/com/pizza/configuration/security/SecurityManager.java)

[Webflux Securiry Context](https://github.com/doctore/Spring5Microservices/blob/master/pizza-service/src/main/java/com/pizza/configuration/security/SecurityContextRepository.java)

[Webflux Security Configuration](https://github.com/doctore/Spring5Microservices/blob/master/pizza-service/src/main/java/com/pizza/configuration/security/WebSecurityConfiguration.java)

As you can see in both ones, an external service is called (using `RestTemplate` in **MVC** and `WebClient` in **Webflux**), to get the required authorization information and decide if the "logged user" pass the required security logic.

You can adapt it in the way you need.

Comment: I'm not using MVC (which is why having a redirect uri is making the flow a bit fuzzy for me) I'm checking the webflux logic, just to clear my point, webflux will help me to first send the client Id (and the other details like scope...) then use the code and make a post request to get a jwt token?

Comment: After reading a bit about webflux, it's very different then what I'm building, as I'm building a simple spring boot rest api, having to apply the webflux approach means I need to change everything if im not mistaken

Comment: If you are creating an Spring Boot Rest API, currently you have only 2 choices: MVC or Webflux. Take a look to your `pom` file, if you see something like `spring-boot-starter-web` => **MVC**. For **Weblux**, you will see `spring-boot-starter-webflux`

Comment: Redirection logic should reside in client code and not in backend. If you do not have/require any UI, and its purely a backend to backend flow, in that case, you may want to consider client credential flow. You can still make use of Authorization grant flow, by introducing two endpoint in ur application. say /login, which should redirect to IDP. And another endpoint say /token where IDP will redirect with the code once user successfully logins in. and in the /token API, read the url param for token and exchange it for idToken/ accesstoken from IDP

Comment: @doctore yes it's starter-web, I will re take a look at your MVC implementation.

Comment: @Partha yes, I would love to stick to backend and have no UI, to make sure I understood your point currently, I make a somewhat fake redirect URI that would call my endpoint, I take the data from the header and proceed to make a post call to replace the code with a token?

Comment: Ok, but as @Partha said a redirection should not be included in backend. In the approach provided by my answer, really you are getting the required authorization info from an external API and manage in your current back. If that can be adapted to your required flow, in my opinion, it is more suitable one than do any redirection

Comment: @bleh10, yes thats what I meant, you can tweak and do. Because IDP does not know or care if the redirection is handled by javascript in browser or by a backend. IDP will append the code in the "redirect url" provided and redirect back. After that its upto you to handle.

Comment: @Partha I'm trying to go your way, but I encountered a weird obstacle, so when I do the first call to my IDP, instead of going straight to my (fake) redirect call, it's requesting a username and password, the tricky part is that its returning the login page as a string  (html) rather than popping up. Any clue how to escape this? EDIT: I think the issue might be cause for the time being im redirecting to localhost:8080/anEndpoint